# how many ways there are to order the word Mississippi in a circle?

Tags: combinatorics

I know that in line you can do it in (11!)/(4! * 4! * 2!).

But how many ways there are to do so in a circle?

Comment: Note that every circle can be unfolded to a line and use the fact that there is only one $M$.

Comment: and if for example i have tthe letters: A,B,C,A,D,R,D,F," how can i calculate the number of ways that i can order them?